# YouTube Reporting API as a Channel Manager

Tags: youtube-api

I have been granted access as a Channel Manager to a Youtube channel within the partner program. I would like to utilize the YouTube Reporting API in order to download bulk reports. I have been able to create jobs and download reports with my own channel, but what do I need to do differently in order to create jobs on behalf of the channel that I am managing? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Alejandro, what value did you use for `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter when you used your own channel to create a report?